# por que pasa esto con &nbsp? HTML

Tags: html, css

Estoy haciendo un pequeno bloc de notas en react native, no tiene nada que ver como HTML como esta en la pregunta, pero hay un metodo que inserta HTML que me esta volviendo loco y no se por que pasa esto,

al metodo le paso la etiqueta que quiero insertar, esto lo hago para permitirle al usuario poder escribir en colores, como en word, en tal caso seria asi:

```
insertHTML(`<span>&nbsp;</span>`); //inserto un &nbsp; primero para que haga un espaciado
insertHTML(`<span style = 'color:red'>hola</span>);  luego inserto la etiqueta

insertHTML(`<span>&nbsp;</span>`); //inserto un &nbsp;
insertHTML(`<span style = 'color:blue'>como</span>);  
    
insertHTML(`<span>&nbsp;</span>`); //inserto un &nbsp; 
insertHTML(`<span style = 'color:violet'>estas</span>);
```

una vez insertado todos los elementos por la consola puedo ver como estan organizados, de esta manera:

```
<span>&nbsp;</span><span style = 'color:red'>hola</span>
<span>&nbsp;</span><span style = 'color:blue'>como</span>
<span>&nbsp;</span><span style = 'color:violet'>estas</span>
```

y en el editor se veria asi con sus respectivos colores y espacios: `hola como estas`

ahora llega el problema, supongamos que quiero unir dos palabras porque se me antojo, seria: `hola comoestas`, vale para hacer esto, tengo que hacer backspace desde la `e` de estas, asi estaria pegado a como, al hacer esto la consola quedaria:

```
<span>&nbsp;</span><span style = 'color:red'>hola</span>
<span>&nbsp;</span><span style = 'color:blue'>como</span>
<span style = 'color:violet'>estas</span>
```

como podran ver el `<span>&nbsp;</span>` que daba espacio entre como y estas ya no esta, pero si hago space entre como y estas para separarlos de nuevo en la consola sale esto:

```
<span>&nbsp;</span><span style = 'color:red'>hola</span>
<span>&nbsp;</span><span style = 'color:blue'>como</span>
<span style="font-size: 1em;"><font color="#ee82ee">&nbsp;estas</font></span>
```

por que no sale el `<span>&nbsp;</span>` que estaba al princpio y este automaticamente mete el   junto a estas dentro de la otra etiqueta?

Comment: Por qué no solo insertas los espacios en los innerHTML de los span con los textos?  "<span style = 'color:red'> hola </span>", html te reconoce el primer espacio entre textos y etiquetas.

Comment: necesito hacerlo de esta forma, porque si no, al juntarlo y luego hacer espacio el ultimo toma el estilo del de adelante

Comment: No deberían, porque cada una está con su etiqueta correspondiente

Comment: exacto, pero por alguna razon pasa, no se si sera por el componente, pero pasa

Comment: Te recomiendo dentro de los inner.. alternar entre comillas simples y dobles, ingresa el contenido general en comillas dobles y el resto en comillas simples o viceversa, esto evita que se rompa el grupo, insertHTML('<span style = "color:red">hola</span>'); por cierto, veo que faltan comillas en algunos inner...

Comment: nada amigo, he intentado de todo, todo todo, pero es que siempre al borrar el &nbsp; de algunas de las palabras y volver a darle space este se concatena junto a la palabra y entra en su span, a la vez el span de la palabra se vuelve en un <font> tag

Comment: No se si copiaste y pegaste el código o se desordenó al colocarlo en la pregunta, pero estan mal manejados espacios y comillas, quita todos los espacios a los style = ""; ahora,,, no se de que forma estás insertando dichos inner..

Comment: No logro entender cuál es el problema. Y, ¿por qué no usas una clase CSS en vez de `&nbsp;`?

Comment: @Elboy, nop, asi funciona, el problema esta solo a la hora de pegarlos y separarlos luego, ellos se concatenan cambiando la etiqueta <span> por <font>